# Logstash apache illegal_argument_exception Invalid format

Tags: timestamp, logstash, grok

I'm getting the illegal_argument_exception error when logstash handles my apache events. Here is the error:

**{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Invalid format: \"15/Feb/2016:14:56:59 -0500\" is malformed at \"/Feb/2016:14:56:59 -0500\""}}}}, :level=>:warn}**

Here is my apache filter:

```
filter {
  if [fields][type] == "apache" {
    grok {
      patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/custom_patterns.txt"]
      match => ["message", "%{COMMONAPACHELOG}" ]
    }
    date {
      locale => "en"
      match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    }
  }
}
```

A Sample date formate from my apache log is 15/Feb/2016:14:53:54 -0500

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
 match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
```

and it works fine, you can try to check the [JODA page](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html). Also check your locale , you may need to use `locale => "en"` or similar to change your locale to really match your format

But i suspect the problem is not in the timestamp, you cut out a important part... in the error, you have the `"reason"=>"failed to parse [fieldname]"`
where the fieldname is the one that is giving the problem... and it might not be the timestamp